# Zipping InputStream, returning InputStream (in memory, no file)

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to do compress an InputStream and return an InputStream:

```
public InputStream compress (InputStream in){
  // Read "in" and write to ZipOutputStream
  // Convert ZipOutputStream into InputStream and return
}
```

I am compressing one file (so I could use GZIP) but will do more in future (so I opted for ZIP). In most of the places:

- [Compress an InputStream with gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036280/compress-an-inputstream-with-gzip)
- [How can I convert ZipInputStream to InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853972/how-can-i-convert-zipinputstream-to-inputstream)

  They use toBytesArray() or getBytes() which do not exist (!) -  [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

My problems are:

1. How do I convert the ZipOutPutStream into InputStream if such methods don't exist?
2. When creating the ZipOutPutStream() there is no default constructor. Should I create a new ZipOutputStrem(new OutputStream() )  ??

Comment: [This](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362) should help.

Comment: Thanks Boris the Spider, but that only shows operation with ZIP files, which I know. I am missing some basic Java I/O I think, not how to compress them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Solved it with a ByteArrayOutputStream which has a .toByteArray()
2. Same here, passing the aforementioned element

Answer (score 11):

Something like that:

```
private InputStream compress(InputStream in, String entryName) throws IOException {
        final int BUFFER = 2048;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER];
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(out);
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryName));
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Just a small note: In the while statement, you should check if in.read(buffer) >= 0. Because if the inputstream isn't ready, it might return 0 bytes read, but the end isn't reached, the stream might be ready later. So it shouldn't be considered finished until it returns -1

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using GZIP?