# ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() generating extra characters

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int size = 4096;
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

while (is.read(bytes, 0, size) != -1)
{
    baos.write(bytes);
    baos.flush();
}
```

When I do:

```
String s = baos.toString();
```

I get `\u0000`-s appended to my string. So, if my character data is only X bytes out of Y, the Y-Z will get prefilled with `\u0000` making it impossible to check for `equals`. What am I doing wrong here? How should I be converting the bytes to a `String` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only be writing as much data as you are reading in each time through the loop:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int size;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

while (size = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length) != -1)
{
    baos.write(bytes, 0, size);
}
baos.flush();
String s = baos.toString();
```

You might consider specifying a specific character set for converting the bytes to a `String`. The no-arg `toString()` method uses the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 4):

The *entire array* (all 4096 bytes) is be written to the output - arrays have no idea of how much "useful data" they contain!

Store how much was *read* into a variable ([`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) returns a useful number) and specify that to the appropriate [`OutputStream.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d,int,int%29) overload to only write a portion (that which contains the useful data) of the array.

While the above change should "fix" the problem, it is generally recommended to use the `string<->byte[]` conversion forms that take in an explicit character set.

Comment: As dumb as it will sound, would you mind actually illustrating it in code?

Comment: @carlspring Ted Hopp has done that for both of us in his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[new String(baos.toByteArray(), 0, strLen, encoding)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: The `0, strLen` isn't necessary.